Printing a GS1 Expanded Databar barcode to a Hengstler C-56 Thermal Printer
I have a thermal printer, the Hengstler C-56, and recently a customer expressed interest in changing their barcodes to the GS1 Expanded databar barcode set. Originally the original barcode was an UPCA 11 character code. With the update, the code will now be 25 characters. The original command is this:
0x1D 0x6B 0x41 0xB barCodeNum PriceCheckDigit 4-digit-price 0xA
Does anyone know how to print a GS1 Expanded databar to a Hengstler C-56 thermal printer?
